# Is there an identity to find (x mod a) + (x mod b) + (x mod c) ...?

Tags: math, number-theory

Given an integer `x` an array of n elements `[a1,a2,a3 ... an]` (both of which will be taken from input stream) , we wish to find out `(x % a1) + (x % a2) + (x % a3) ... + (x % an)`.  `x` will be given after the taking array as the input.

Since this is part of a bigger problem, I want to find it out preferably in `O(1)` or `O(logn)` time (excluding `O(n)` time for taking in the array).

When I will take the input array, I will simultaneously calculate the sum of the complete array, and wish to bring it into a format similar to `(x % (a1 + a2 + a3 ... an))`. Is there any identity similar to this?

This is not my actual problem. I just wish to meet my time complexity requirements. Once the array is taken as input, after that, `multiple numbers` will be given ... and I have to calculate the answer for each of them in `O(1)` or `O(logn)` time.

You may assume that `x` is always one of the elements of the array itself, i.e., there are at max `n` possible values of `x`. The array can have up to `1e5 elements` and each integer element lies in the closed interval `[1, 1e5]`.

Comment: Why not have an accumulator variable, and then as you are taking in input for the array do `accumulator += x % input`?

Comment: Why would it be problematic to calculate this in `O(n)`? Your total time complexity will remain `O(n)` as you've already mentioned, and if you do this while taking in the array (and you do not need `[a1,a2,..]` later on) then the space complexity will be `O(1)`, in the other algorithm

Comment: Actually, I had to reframe the question a bit... This is not my actual problem. I just want to meet my time complexity requirements. Once taken the array as an input, after that, multiple numbers will be given ... and I have to calculate the answer for each of them in `O(1)` time.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghal ahhh, that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: `x mod array_element` is already `O(1)`. If you want to do something for N array elements it is necessarily `O(N)` (unless you find a way to not use every element). Its not clear what complexity requirelemtns you want to meet

Comment: in other words: `a1 + a2 + ... + aN` has same complexity as `x % a1 + x % a2 ... + x%aN`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I wish to find `x mod array_element` for every element and add them up and get the answer in `O(1)` time, maybe with some kind of `O(n)` preprocessing of the array while taking it as an input. There will be multiple such `x` once the array is taken as input. I repeat, all the `x` will be given after taking array as input.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I think I get it: The input array `[a1...]` is given, and during that things can be calculated, but after that `x1,x2 etc` will be given and for those `x1 % [a1,a2,...]` have to be `O(1)`

Comment: OP is asking if there is a way to create a cached representation of ` [a1, a2,...]` so that an arbitrary number of Xs can be calculated against it, each in O(1) time. This is a perfectly reasonable request.

Comment: @Lala5th exactly!

Comment: @Frank now I get it :)

Comment: This is close https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195325/how-to-calculate-the-sum-of-remainders-of-n and may point someone is a better direction  In fact this question looks a better fit for that site.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghal Is there any structure to either the Xs or the As? For example, are the As pairwise coprime? Consecutive integers? Are the Xs powers of two? If both Xs and As are completely arbitrary integers, I don't think there is a solution other than the naive one.

Comment: This is a very nasty solution (incredibly large time complexity to preprocess), but you can find the smallest common multiple (scm) of `[a1...an]` and create a `map` of `{i, sum}` for `i < scm`, after that every calculation is `int res = sums[x % scm]`, where `sums` is the map where you calculated the sums. If you know `[a1..an]` compile time you might want to implement a `constexpr map`.

Comment: @njuffa and others - Actually, you may assume that `x` is always one of the elements of the array itself (really sorry for not telling that earlier).

Comment: @AbhinavSinghal If there are only n possible `x` values, you could simply calculate them all ahead of time in a LUT and discard the `a`s entirely.

Comment: @Frank yes there are only n possible values of x... Also, what is LUT?

Comment: @AbhinavSinghal A **L**ook**u**p **T**able. a simple `std::unordered_map<int, int>` can do the trick.

Comment: your last comment made the question rather unclear. You can calculate all `n` possible results as part of preprocessing, using them later is then only O(1)

Comment: @ 463035818_is_not_a_number The problem is that that will be an `O(n^2)` Preprocessing which I cannot afford to do.

Comment: I have doubts that there is a `O(n)` preprocessing. Perhaps some clever algorithm can get it down to something like `O(n log n)` but i dont believe you can get all `a_i % a_j` in linear time and you need those to get the later result in `O(1)`

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). This is not a C++ question, it should not be tagged with [tag:c++].

Comment: Although interesting, this really seems like a mathematics question rather than a programming one. Consider math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Are there any other constraints that you haven't mentioned? Are the numbers involved all within some range, for example?

Comment: Interesting to note, if the array is sorted and has only positive number (if negative are present, you need to sort by absolute value), the first part of the final value is the partial sum of the array itself till the position of the searched value (where it will be 0).

Comment: @Caleb As mentioned in the question all integers lie in the closed interval `[1, 1e5]`